# ef core power tools many to many

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-power-tools, ef-core-7.0

We're using Entity Framework Core 7 along with EF Core Power tools to reverse engineer our SQL Sever db.  We have a many to many relationship in our db:
Staff -> Role
which in db has a mapping table in between StaffRole.

When running EF core power tools I see it making 3 tables, one of each, with Staff having a Collection of StaffRoles and StaffRole has a link to both Staff and Role.  Role again has a Collection of StaffRoles.

I wanted to use Skip Navigation to avoid the StaffRole link being there in both Staff and Role, is that possible with EF Core PowerTools?  I have the "Use many to many entity (EF Core 6 or later)" option.

Screenshots (here the option is unchecked, but same results if checked or unchecked):
[image]
[image]
[image]

TbStaff has:
[image]

TbRole has:
[image]

DbContext OnModelCreating has the below for the TbStaffRole table:
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just uncheck that option and you will not get the extra entity generated.

Comment: tried both check and uncheck, it produced the same result. I will update the post with screenshots if needed.

Comment: Or post an issue with repro details in the EF Core Power Tools repository

Comment: I am having the same issue. Regardless if 'use many to many entities' is check or unchecked the result is the same. If you select the JOIN table in the 'Choose Your Database Objects" window of EF Core Power Tools, the JOIN table will be generated as an Entity. Was an issue ever created for this in the repo on GitHub?

Comment: @Pavel Please create an repro on Github